# Uncaught reference error onclick()

Tags: javascript

```
<button id="btnBleed" class="tab-button" onclick="ClearStatus()" tabindex="-1">BLEED</button>
```

When the button is clicked:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ClearStatus is not defined

but the function is clearly defined in the script.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="button-holder">
        @if (Model.HasAccessToFill == "true")
        {
            <button id="btnstandardFill" class="tab-button selected" onclick="ClearStatus()">STANDARD FILL</button>
            <button id="btnFill" class="tab-button" >FILL</button>
        }

        @if (Model.HasAccessToBleed == "true" && Model.CurrentBalance != 0.0)
        {
            <button id="btnBleed" class="tab-button" onclick="ClearStatus()">BLEED</button>
        }
        @if (Model.HasAccessToAdjust == "true")
        {
            <button id="btnAdjustmentP" class="tab-button" onclick="ClearStatus()">ADJUSTMENT +</button>
            if (Model.CurrentBalance != 0.0)
            {
            <button id="btnAdjustment" class="tab-button" onclick="ClearStatus()">ADJUSTMENT -</button>
            }
        }
        @if (Model.HasAccessToDrop == "true")
        {
            <button id="btnSDrop" class="tab-button" onclick="ClearStatus()">DROP</button>
            <button id="btnFINALDrop" class="tab-button" onclick="ClearStatus()">FINAL DROP</button>
        }
    </div>
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ClearStatus()
    {
        $('.status-holder span').html("");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What template language is that? Do you get any others in the console? Could the `{...}` of the function body accidentally be interpreted by the template system (and therefore causing the function not to be defined)?

Comment: Try to put your function inside the page of the code.. `<script>your function</script>`

Comment: i tried insering the code in <script>your function</script> still i get the error message clearstatus not defined

Comment: Do you see the `ClearStatus` function when you view the source code of the resulting html page in your browser? Like *Felix* already asked: What kind of template (the @ thing) language are you using?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/fupudi/1/edit?html,output — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: check this fiddle example. there isn't any issue. https://jsfiddle.net/ashishpce2007/phc3qbw1/